# PHP script to get cell based on first column cell of mysql table

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am trying implement a search activity which gets data from a mysql table based on a search.

I want to write a PHP script to use the string entered into the EditText and get the adjacent cell.

For example, Imagine there are two columns of the mysql table: Firstname and surname; I would like to be able to get the surname by searching the Firstname (Entering the Firstname into the EditText. I know this may require a `SELECT Surname FROM Names WHERE ...` query but how do I indicate the variable from my Java class?

The PHP script so Far:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("androidapp");
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT surname WHERE $get'fname'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Also, is the HttpGet method appropriate or HttPost method to do this, the result should display the surname in a TextView

Comment: The amount of things I understood from your question is too damn low! Seriously, I understood nothing, please rephrase your question to explain better what you have, and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Don't use the mysql_* functions!  They're deprecated in all but name and aren't fully compatible with MySQL 5

Comment: I Have updated it, hopefully it makes more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume you want to send and receive data from php to java (android) through http post or http get. correct me if i am wrong.

basically what you want php to return is the row that matches the first name in the table.

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("androidapp");

$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT surname FROM names WHERE fname = '$fname'");

//if you want only one record then
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo json_encode($row);

mysql_close();
```

always remember to escape the data for any sql injection with php's `mysql_real_escape_string()` function. ans also i would prefer HTTP POST.

from your android application you will have to send a http request to the server where the PHP script is.

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're doing with your query but I'd use

```
$fname = addslashes($_GET['fname']);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT surname FROM Names WHERE fname='$fname'");
...
```

Clearly, you pass `fname=whatever` in the query.

GET is absolutely fine. HTTP specifies a GET request as one that returns information from the server and has no other side-effects (such as modifying the database).

Answer (score -2):

I guess you have an Android application (written in Java) that communicate with a sort of web service coded in PHP.

Therefore, your PHP application should behave like any web service.

IN PHP, you can retrieve the parameters given to the script using the $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST global variables.

- $_GET contains only parameters send by the GET method (that is
  directly in the URL).
- $_POST contains only parameters send by the POST method (that is
  nested in the http query).
- $_REQUEST is a compilation of $_GET + $_POST.

For a web application, $_REQUEST is often the best solution, so you allow any methods (POST/GET) used by the caller. If you want to fix only one, choose $_POST or $_GET.

Therefore,

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT surname WHERE firstname='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['fname'])."'");
```

Don't forget to escape the parameter with `mysql_real_escape_string()` in order to prevent from SQL injection.

Comment: $_REQUEST is extremely dangerous, don't use it!  You can't trust input if you don't know where it came from.

Comment: $_REQUEST only contains $_GET + $_POST ($_COOKIES is not in the default configuration in PHP 5.3). You said "You can't trust input if you don't know where it came from", but in fact a web app cannot trust input at all, you cannot know where it comes from since a basic knower can change the input as he wishes. Therefore, your application must check the data at the server side. So you're wrong, $_REQUEST is no more dangerous than $_GET,  $_POST, (only under very specific circumstances and when cookies are includes) or give me an example of you're assertion.

Comment: Just because it's off by default doesn't mean you can depend on it being off.  Quite the opposite, in fact.  When it comes to security, you must always assume the worst.  As for an example, http://www.suspekt.org/2008/10/01/php-53-and-delayed-cross-site-request-forgerieshijacking/ and aside from that, a webapp that relies on $_REQUEST can't be RESTful.

Comment: You have to assume the worst, I agree with that, but that includes that any value in the $_COOKIES can also be present in both $_GET + and $_POST. If it's dangerous in $_COOKIES then it is dangerous in $_GET and dangerous in $_POST too.